# Blank page first time access site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

good evening, I noticed that if I try to access the site for the first time, it only loads the cookies and the page remains white, as soon as reloading works.  Do you know what it can be?
is it possible because cookies are set to security true?

No error display only white page

Comment: Check your server error log. Blank page in most cases means 500 response code.

Comment: on php : Try to enable Error Reporting !

Comment: No error display

Comment: Not sure how your code looks like, but are there any checks like `if (!$_COOKIE..) { exit; }` type deals? Looks like a basic check that fails/terminates on initial page initialization (code-wise).

Comment: try to use developer tools of browser and find more details about the error. otherwise, there are many reasons for this kind of behaviour.